# How to sort objects by a derived calculation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a class called `Team` that has wins and losses. 
I want to be able to sort teams by a `win_pct` which should be the ratio of wins to total games played (i.e. `wins.count()/(wins.count() + losses.count())`).

```
class Team(TimestampModerated):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
    wins = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='related_wins')
    losses = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='related_losses')

    def num_wins(self):
        return self.wins.count()

    def num_losses(self):
        return self.losses.count()

    def win_pct(self):
        return self.wins.count()/(self.wins.count() + self.losses.count())
```

So, in my view I have something like this:

```
@list_route
def teams_list(self, request):
    teams = Team.objects.all().order_by('-win_pct')
    page = self.paginate_queryset(teams)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(teams, many=True)
    return Response(
        data=serializer.data
    )
```

But it just gives an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'win_pct' into a field. Choices are: created, id, losses, moderation_code, related_losses, related_wins, name, updated, wins
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
from django.db.models import Count
teams = Team.objects.all().annotate(
    win_pct=(Count('wins')/(Count('wins')+Count('losses')))).order_by('win_pct')
```